# Скрытное получение id пользователя Вк

Tags: vkontakte-api

каким образом можно скрытно получить лишь один id пользователя Вк?
Через API требуется подтверждение пользователем
Кросс-доменность не позволяет получить данные с сайта JS запросом

Comment: [Аналогичный вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/364168/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-id-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82)

@maxleo напр. для клонирования сервиса SocFishing

Comment: @Sergiks, был вопрос - но не было достойного ответа.
Вопрос состоит в том, чтобы пользователю не кликать никакие кнопки подтверждения

Comment: @Ni55aN, в ходе дискуссии пришли к выводу, что «белых» методов шпионить нет и не будет, а существующие решения используют уязвимости в браузерах, которые уже ликвидированы в свежих версиях.

Answer (score 1):

Попытки использования ajax или frame не дали никакого результата из-за соображения безопасности браузеров.

Единственный вариант - Open API

**Но есть сложность: можно получить id только того, кто установил приложение!! Как быть с этим?**

1. [создать приложение](https://vk.com/editapp?act=create)
2. подключить     `http://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js`
3. выполнить в нужном для вас месте
           следующий скрипт:

> ```
> VK.init({
>   apiId: ВАШ_API_ID
> });
>
> VK.Auth.getLoginStatus(function(response){
>  if (response.session) {
>     alert('Юзер авторизирован под id : '+response.session.mid);
>   } else {
>     alert('Юзер не авторизирован ВК');
>   }
> });
> ```